# Consumir WebService ASMX (.Net) desde PHP

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, webservice

Tengo un WebService con extension `ASMX` hecho en .Net corriendo en `IIS` en un servidor de mi red local `ip:x.x.x.10`.
La URL de mi WebService es http://x.x.x.10:8093/ws_lista, requiere un parametro `codigo` de tipo `int` y retorna un `DataTable`.
Lo quiero invocar desde mi entorno de desarrollo  en mi equipo local OSX. Ya sea desde PHP o Javascript.

¿Cómo puedo hacer eso y además no tener problemas de dominios cruzados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu webservices debe exponer un xml al agregar a la dirección '?WSDL', con ese xml generas un objeto SoapClient

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://testurl/webservice.asmx?WSDL");
$params = array('codigo' => $parametro);
$result = $client->miMetodo($params);
```

// It's a clear code

Comment: gracias, funciona. Pero ahora como puedo convertir ese resutado en json o un array algo mas legible?

Comment: coloca el código de como es devuelto, lo mas probable que venga serializado, y puedes ocupar `deserialize`

Comment: el ws retorna un datatable. por el lado de php puso lo que me dijiste mas un print_r($result), que me devuelve : los datos pero con esto antes: stdClass Object ( [getClientesResult] => stdClass Object ( [any] =>

Comment: Es un objeto, puedes acceder a el utilizando `$result->getClientesResult`, es lo que indica stdClass, la clase base de php